# How communicate library (.so) with application (.apk)?

Tags: android, apk

I have a library (.so) that is loaded by my Android application.
This library detects kernel events (that aren't unavailable using Java) and I need to send the events information to the main application.
How I can make this?
Using sockets to communicate .so and .apk code is the main option?
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the Android NDK: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can write JNI layer to interact with native code.

> JNI is the Java Native Interface. It defines a way for managed code (written in the Java programming language) to interact with native code (written in C/C++). It's vendor-neutral, has support for loading code from dynamic shared libraries, and while cumbersome at times is reasonably efficient.